# Instagram /tag/search looks like getting results out of sandbox for me, how come

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

All endpoints like for hashtag, work in sandbox and get info in json from within sandbox users in public_content scope with users info.

Yet "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=cat&access_token=..." brings me result apparantly out of sandbox, results I have not seen before, and only with items include "data: name, media_count", without user info.

Question 1, is it really getting out of sandbox, is it a bug?

Question2, why not user info then, cause I can use more info, Image URL for example, why not? am I missing something?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=snowy&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

This endpoint only gives you **similar hashtag name** and **count** for the search term.

Documentation here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_search

If you want all photos and user details for a hashtag then use this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: thanks but do you know why it behaves and get results as if it works out of sandbox ? which is not expected.

Comment: there is no user info in that API response so u get all results (hashtags name and count)